# What was Cameron's model number in the Sarah Connor Chronicles?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

What was Cameron (Summer Glau)'s model number? I know it doesn't say it anywhere in the show, but perhaps someone knows it from another source.

Comment: By the way, the nomenclature for Terminators is a bit confusing, but "model" is mostly used for how they look, while "series" is the generation number (or how advanced they are). At east from T2 onwards; Arnie was just a "T-101" in T1, but a "series 800 model 101" in T2.

Answer (score 8):

It's never specifically stated. There's some internet chatter (based on the poster below) that she's a **[TOK715](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/TOK715?file=T0K715.jpg)** but this may simply be an embellishment of the graphic artist.

In the pilot episode, she specifically avoids the question

> **John:** *What model are you? Are you new? You seem... different.*
>
> **Cameron :** *I am.*

And in other posters she's just designated as type : Cameron.

Her chassis bears a superficial similarity to the T-888 so she may be some kind of heavily customised [T-888](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-888) infiltration unit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I disagree with the chassis being similar to the T-888. It's not just heavily customized - it appears to be a different one altogether. Coupled with her ability to perfectly mimic emotion in the pilot, I think she's actually some sort of advanced infiltration model - perhaps a prototype. Keep in mind, the T-1000 could mimic human emotion as well when needed, whereas the T-888 could not. Either way... she has a REALLY nice chassis :)

Comment: @omegacron - it's not her chassis that I'm interested in. ..

Comment: I'm with Richard, she must be very similar to a T-888, as that's what Cromartie/John Henry is and in the finale Cameron gives him her chip. Additionally, the episode 'Allison from Palmdale' heavily implies that she's an infiltrator.

Answer (score -1):

While the canon never mentioned exact series number of Cameron, a promotional poster of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* says that Cameron is of Terminator Class **TOK715**. So, fans are speculating that she may be T-715.

(Source: [Terminator Wikia](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/TOK715))